# React - Truncate markdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, truncate

I have a string of some markdown text in it (`"**Bold** *Italic*"`) and I need it to be rendered in React. This itself is simple enough, I can just use the `react-markdown` module and voila.

I need the text to only span 1 line, if more than that then it should be truncated with an ellipsis. For this on its own I would use `react-truncate`.

The problem is that when I combine the use of these 2 modules, all of the markdown formatting (bold and italics) is gone. It just renders as plain text in a `span`.

How do I render markdown whilst truncating it in React?

This is my code so far:

```
<Truncate lines={1}>
  <ReactMarkdown source={"**Bold** *Italic*"} />
</Truncate>
```

Comment: Would you be ok with a CSS solution? Single like text truncation is simple enough for CSS. Multiline gets a little tricky/ and unsupported.

Comment: All the CSS solutions I have found are not very cross-browser compatible at all. I was looking for a more universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If it's one line, `Trauncuate` might be an overkill, i suggest a `css` solution :

```css
#test{
  width: 300px;  
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  resize: both;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" >
  Hello world <b>Hello world</b> Hello world <i>Hello world</i> Hello world <b>Hello world</b> 
</div>
```

Comment: All the CSS solutions I have found are not very cross-browser compatible at all. I was looking for a more universal solution.

Comment: `text-overflow` has been around for quite some time and it seems pretty universal : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow